# Sum up the reputation of the marked part of the reputation-graph

Tags: feature-request, reputation-graph

I like the feature of marking a part of the reputation-graph to get a better view of the selected part. I would like to have the feature, that the sum of the reputation in the selected area is displayed next to the graph.

I this way I can easily calculate the earned reputation of the last month/year/self selected time interval without adding the reputation day by day by my own (what is very annoying for a bigger selection).

This feature is not very important, but would be a nice add-on for the history view.